# Can I connect my laptop's (VAIO VPCEB26FG) hard disk to my desktop's sata cable and to desktop's SMPS power supply and take data backup?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, backup, sata

Can I connect my laptop's (VAIO model VPCEB26FG) hard disk to my desktop's SATA cable and to desktop's power cable supplied by SMPS and take data backup? Or does it cause voltage issues and damage the hard disk? Please explain what happens.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your laptop drive in your towers power and sata plugs. Your looking to see if the power supplies design for efficient power use will harm the HDD. It will not.

The SMPS is performing on off cycles (very fast) to eliminate energy loss. The load to the computer and other attachments, including hard drives are not affected by this.

Comment: Hi @Carl B. Thank you very much for replying! :)  Honestly saying I didn't understand your explanation on how it doesn't affect or burn hard disk because of voltage coming from 850 Watts SMPS. can you please explain the same in simple language?

Comment: @Naresh - Simply, the connectors are SATA with 3.3 V supplied along with 5 V and 12 V supplies in the connector, they follow a voltage standard. If this were a Slim optical for example, it requires different set up / connector that allows 5.5 v vs 12v. Thus, the connector for SATA will not fit on a Slim Sata and visa versa. I have used laptop HDDs in my tower before from a scrap laptop for some storage.

Answer (score 0):

As [SATA signal/data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sata#Data_connector) connectors are standarized, so - if you match connectors - SATA data connection will be compatible.

SATA [power connectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sata#Power_connectors) are standarized too. However, to be completely sure of the power cable compatibility - it is general rule for electrical appliances - you should look at HDD [rating plate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rating_%28electrical%29) (part of HDD sticker):
[image: HDD rating plate]

If your HDD allows power cable voltage it will be OK.

Comment: Hi @g2mk, But there's isn't any table on laptop's hard drive to confirm. Thanks alot for replying!  :)

Comment: @Naresh I mean rating plate.

Comment: The voltage on which devices are working is standardized. If the connector fits, it will work.